# looping through json response and sum value

Tags: jquery, sum

I am trying to sum values getting from json response:

**JS Code**

```
var daySum = {};
$.each(json, function (i, v) {      
    date = Number(v.eDate.split('.')[0]);
    eValue = Number(v.eValue);
    daySum[date] += eValue; 
    console.log(date); //14 , 18 , 19, 19
    console.log(eValue); //30.00 , 20.00 , 20.50, 14.30
});
console.log(daySum); //Object { 14=NaN, 18=NaN, 19=NaN}
```

**JSON structure :**

```
[
  {
    "eDate": "14.06.2013",
    "eValue": "30.00"
  },
  {
    "eDate": "18.06.2013",
    "eValue": "20.00"
  },
  {
    "eDate": "19.06.2013",
    "eValue": "20.50"
  },
  {
    "eDate": "19.06.2013",
    "eValue": "14.30"
  }
]
```

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing what `json` is.

Comment: it was typo, only here

Comment: In your both `console.log()` statements in the `$.each()`, try running a `typeof` on both `date` and `eValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`daySum[date] += eValue;` adds `eValue` to the current value of `daySum[date]`. In the event that `daySum` doesn't have a key with the name of `date`, you'll be adding together `undefined` and a number:

```
> undefined + 2
NaN
```

There's the source of your error. Now to fix it, you need to check to see if the key exists beforehand:

```
if (date in daySum) {
    daySum[date] += eValue;
} else {
    daySum[date] = eValue;
}
```

Also, don't omit `var` when declaring variables. You'll make them globally scoped, which isn't something you want to do with every variable.